# Is it possible to check if the SQLITE cache is hot or cold?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a ~5GB python SQLITE3 database (accessed using SQLalchemy) that is installed on a number of machines with varying architectures. Queries to this database can take dramatically longer (up to 100x) if the SQLite cache is cold.

If I know the cache is cold, I can change the query to make it faster by essentially reading the entire table in chunks and filtering the data I want out of every chunk. However, this changed query will still be slower than the normal query on a hot cache, so I can't use it all the time.

Is there any way to check if the cache is hot or cold using SQLalchemy / SQLITE3?